# Xamarin Studios Can't find References for System.Collections?

Tags: collections, xamarin, assembly-references

I'm trying to add a Systems.Collections reference in my .cs code in Xamarin Studios, however I failed to find this in the list of references in Xamarin Studios under > References > Edit References. The listed packages in Xamarin are all in .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a System.Collections dll.  Most of the System.Collections classes are included in the System.dll.

Comment: Ok I understand, unlike something like LINQ to XML where we need to import it. Where are all the dlls stored?